# What is wrong with this SVG file?

Tags: html, css, svg

Can somebody tell me how to fix this margins of my `::before` element? Any `margin: -2px` doesn't work, any paddings... when I resize page, margins are still visible, once at top of img, once on sides... SVG file doesn't have this blue lines on its sides.

[image]

```css
.container {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  height: 1000px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.media {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 408px;
  height: 155px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.media img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.media::before{
  content: "";
  background-image: url(https://svgshare.com/i/HRx.svg);
  position: absolute;
  background-position: center center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="media">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/iD4ERTU.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

SVG

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="512" height="513" viewBox="0 0 512 513"><defs><style>.a{fill:#f7f7f7;}.b{fill:#004fa3;}.c{clip-path:url(#a);}.d{fill:#2699fb;}.e{clip-path:url(#b);}.f,.h{fill:none;}.f{stroke:#0092ff;}.g{stroke:none;}</style><clipPath id="a"><rect class="a" width="512" height="513"/></clipPath><clipPath id="b"><ellipse class="b" cx="193.129" cy="193.129" rx="193.129" ry="193.129" transform="translate(511.391 163.225) rotate(115)"/></clipPath></defs><g class="c"><path class="d" d="M104.741,309.74S-53.3,342.253,18.88,249.888,133.249,220.239,185.7,134.716,186.843-3.264,266.665.158s6.842,255.431,6.842,255.431Z" transform="translate(315.585 237.501) rotate(129)"/><path class="a" d="M-962-168h-512V-680h512v512Zm-257.146-435.439a180.791,180.791,0,0,0-163.286,103.993,178.856,178.856,0,0,0-6.01,137.662,178.855,178.855,0,0,0,93.092,101.592,178.531,178.531,0,0,0,75.969,16.911h.014A180.775,180.775,0,0,0-1056.1-347.274c41.954-89.971,2.89-197.3-87.08-239.254A178.493,178.493,0,0,0-1219.146-603.439Z" transform="translate(1474 680)"/><g transform="translate(330.302 352.173)"><ellipse class="d" cx="3.691" cy="3.691" rx="3.691" ry="3.691"/><ellipse class="d" cx="3.691" cy="3.691" rx="3.691" ry="3.691" transform="translate(0 79.363)"/><ellipse class="d" cx="3.691" cy="3.691" rx="3.691" ry="3.691" transform="translate(0 39.679)"/><ellipse class="d" cx="3.691" cy="3.691" rx="3.691" ry="3.691" transform="translate(39.68)"/><ellipse class="d" cx="3.691" cy="3.691" rx="3.691" ry="3.691" transform="translate(39.68 79.363)"/><ellipse class="d" cx="3.691" cy="3.691" rx="3.691" ry="3.691" transform="translate(39.68 39.679)"/><ellipse class="d" cx="3.691" cy="3.691" rx="3.691" ry="3.691" transform="translate(79.362)"/><ellipse class="d" cx="3.691" cy="3.691" rx="3.691" ry="3.691" transform="translate(79.362 79.363)"/><ellipse class="d" cx="3.691" cy="3.691" rx="3.691" ry="3.691" transform="translate(79.362 39.679)"/></g><g class="e"><g class="f" transform="translate(511.391 163.225) rotate(115)"><ellipse class="g" cx="193.129" cy="193.129" rx="193.129" ry="193.129"/><ellipse class="h" cx="193.129" cy="193.129" rx="192.629" ry="192.629"/></g><g transform="translate(330.302 352.173)"><ellipse class="d" cx="3.691" cy="3.691" rx="3.691" ry="3.691"/><ellipse class="d" cx="3.691" cy="3.691" rx="3.691" ry="3.691" transform="translate(0 79.363)"/><ellipse class="d" cx="3.691" cy="3.691" rx="3.691" ry="3.691" transform="translate(0 39.679)"/><ellipse class="d" cx="3.691" cy="3.691" rx="3.691" ry="3.691" transform="translate(39.68)"/><ellipse class="d" cx="3.691" cy="3.691" rx="3.691" ry="3.691" transform="translate(39.68 79.363)"/><ellipse class="d" cx="3.691" cy="3.691" rx="3.691" ry="3.691" transform="translate(39.68 39.679)"/><ellipse class="d" cx="3.691" cy="3.691" rx="3.691" ry="3.691" transform="translate(79.362)"/><ellipse class="d" cx="3.691" cy="3.691" rx="3.691" ry="3.691" transform="translate(79.362 79.363)"/><ellipse class="d" cx="3.691" cy="3.691" rx="3.691" ry="3.691" transform="translate(79.362 39.679)"/></g><g class="f" transform="translate(511.391 163.225) rotate(115)"><ellipse class="g" cx="193.129" cy="193.129" rx="193.129" ry="193.129"/><ellipse class="h" cx="193.129" cy="193.129" rx="192.629" ry="192.629"/></g></g></g></svg>
```

Comment: i don't know why you want to use that background image for but you can just easily create a div and give it the same color(much faster) as for why there are edges it might be your viewbox and width which is 1px smaller than height you can try changing them to have both the same value. i've made a codepen with div background of that color that you have https://codepen.io/DevKosov/pen/MWYzoWO

Comment: The thing is that I need <img> inside `.media`, there are pictures, I can't replace it with div with background :(

Comment: Oh okay. In my opinion you should change the SVG viewport to `viewbox="0 0 512 512" and remove height and width from it and you should be good

Comment: I changed viewbox to `0 0 512 512` (not `0 0 512 513`) and I also changed all `513` to `512`, but it didn't help.

Comment: It works with me itst because you have width and height attributes in your svg file i'd recommend optimising every svg file from https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/ and check my version of your svg file https://codepen.io/DevKosov/pen/MWYzoWO

Comment: I deleted it, but there's still a problem :(

Comment: here's the svg https://res.cloudinary.com/devkosov/image/upload/v1579515102/test_drrlxj.svg

Comment: I can't see any diffrence between my svg and yours svg :D When I scale page in browser to 75% sometimes on some resolutions there are still that margins on sides, but I think I'll leave it alone... Thanks.

Comment: Hey sorry i was working, there are margins on the sides because of your container background color and what you can do is change the img width and height to 99%

Comment: Even `width: 5%;` and `height: 5%` on image not helps :D

Comment: It is working with my SVG https://codepen.io/DevKosov/pen/MWYzoWO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjust your `viewBox` size so it is slightly smaller than the grey square.  At the moment rounding and pixel alignment, together with anti-aliasing bleed-through, means the blue JPEG underneath is slightly visible on the edges.  By shrinking the viewBox, we are effectively making the grey square a fraction bigger, hiding the bleed-through.

1. Set `viewBox="1 1 510 511" (shrink viewBox by 1 unit on each side)
2. *(Optional)* Remove the `width="512" height="513"` attributes.

Result:

```css
.container {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  height: 1000px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.media {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 408px;
  height: 155px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.media img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.media::before{
  content: "";
  background-image: url(https://svgshare.com/i/HPM.svg);
  position: absolute;
  background-position: center center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="media">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/iD4ERTU.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```